# What is writing { } in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On this page (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), I found this writing: `{ }`.

`const { PI } = Math;`

Does it have a particular name, so that I can get more information about it, and especially what does it produce?

Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: it is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where a property of an object is now a variable with the same name.

Comment: In this case, it is the same as writing: "var myObject = { x : 1 }; var x = myObject.x;" no ? I must have missed something...

Comment: that a longer form. but you could use more properties at the same moment for destructuring.

Comment: All right, I see, all his interest lies in the destructuring of several properties. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is called "[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)".  You can think of it as being equivalent to:

```
const PI = Math.PI;
```

…but a little more compact.  It really shines when being used to pluck *multiple* properties off an object:

```
const { foo, bar, baz } = require('quux').util;
```

You can also destructure arrays using `[ ]`:

```
const [ first, second, third ] = array;
```

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets in javascript typically represent an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), but in this case, it is a ["destructuring assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). For example:

```
const obj = { value: 'hello world' };
const {value} = obj;
console.log(value); // outputs: hello world
```